# How to get duration of each build steps

Tags: teamcity, rest

Here is a build configuration with 24 steps.
With API, I can get the total build time duration. How can I get each duration of 24 steps?
https://[server]/app/rest/builds/id:[123]/

```
<startDate>20210122T123050+0000</startDate>
<finishDate>20210122T123115+0000</finishDate>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it simplier by using the [TeamCity Service Messages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/service-messages.html#Supported+test+service+messages)

For example, you can use progress messages

```
##teamcity[progressMessage '<message>']
```

or statistics:

```
##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='<valueTypeKey>' value='<value>']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `https://[tc_server]/app/rest/builds/id:[id]/statistics` api

```
curl -u user:password https://myserver.com/app/rest/builds/id:123/statistics -H accept:application/json

{"count":18,"property":[{"name":"ArtifactsSize","value":"28734525"},{"name":"BuildDuration","value":"2860858"},{"name":"BuildDurationNetTime","value":"2852922"},{"name":"buildStageDuration:artifactsPublishing","value":"3976"},{"name":"buildStageDuration:buildFinishing","value":"221"},{"name":"buildStageDuration:buildStepRUNNER_1","value":"26715"},{"name":"buildStageDuration:buildStepRUNNER_4","value":"1517192"},{"name":"buildStageDuration:buildStepRUNNER_5","value":"1233555"},{"name":"buildStageDuration:buildStepRUNNER_6","value":"75460"},{"name":"buildStageDuration:firstStepPreparation","value":"2"},{"name":"buildStageDuration:sourcesUpdate","value":"3408"},{"name":"buildStageDuration:toolsUpdating","value":"1"},{"name":"BuildTestStatus","value":"1"},{"name":"queueWaitReason:Checking_for_changes_is_in_progress","value":"810"},{"name":"serverSideBuildFinishing","value":"92"},{"name":"SuccessRate","value":"1"},{"name":"TimeSpentInQueue","value":"1057"},{"name":"VisibleArtifactsSize","value":"18049068"}]}
```

in response there are durations for build steps
`{"name":"buildStageDuration:buildStepRUNNER_1","value":"26715"},`
`{"name":"buildStageDuration:buildStepRUNNER_4","value":"1517192"},`
`{"name":"buildStageDuration:buildStepRUNNER_5","value":"1233555"},`
`{"name":"buildStageDuration:buildStepRUNNER_6","value":"75460"}`

ps there are not all build steps in response (no 2 and 3). it means they were skipped or probably duration was < 1s